# How to add .xml on a URL of a .NET MVC website?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, url

When I enter on a specific page on my **ASP.NET** **mvc** website (MVC v.4 - .NET Framework v.4.8 - Visual Studio 2017) 
`https://www.mywebsite.com/product/facebook`an XML file loads.
 My problem is that I want to add the `.xml` at the end of the URL so it becomes like this `https://www.mywebsite.com/product/facebook.xml` 

**but** mvc framework works with Extensionless URLs only (by default).

I have tried to change the web.config file at system.webServer > handlers but it didn't work.

Any Ideas on how to achieve this please?

Comment: What did you try? Which *specific* MVC and runtime version are you using? Things changed from 4.0 to 4.5. Which handlers did you modify? Without that information this could *easily* get closed as a duplicate of something you may have already tried

Comment: I will edit my question. Thank you!

Comment: Check [Serving URLs with File Extensions in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/nov/13/serving-urls-with-file-extensions-in-an-aspnet-mvc-application) too. It explains that simply modifying the handler isn't enough as the extension conflicts with MVC's routing. Adding a URL rewrite rule may be the easiest solution

Comment: PS: You didn't post what you tried

Comment: I don't remember to be honest because I have tried all day to fix this problem, but whatever it was... it didn't work. Since you know the solution, why don't you post an answer?